# Freeze to a black screen and then restart

Tags: freeze

I just installed Ubuntu, haven't changed anything. I'm just at the desktop opening stuff like firefox or anything and then the screen freezes but the mouse still can be moved. Then after about 10 seconds a black screen appears and shows this:

`[  121.601977 nouveau E[Xorg[1463]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1463]]`

My Ubuntu is 14 and here are my specs:

- 8gb ram
- nVidia gtx580 gpu
- 3.4k 8core cpu

Please help its critical

Comment: I'd like to know a few things, such as; (1) Prior to installing it did try running Ubuntu on this PC from the "live cd/dvd media" or did you dive right into the installation without making sure your computer was ubuntu compliant?  (2) During installation, was your computer connected to the internet by any means?  (3) Is this a dual-boot installation?  and last but not least (4) By "critical" does that mean you are not the owner of the computer in question?

Comment: (1. I only put it into a dvd and installed it nothing else
(2. No connection during installation
(3. No, ubuntu is the only OS on the system 
(4. by critical I mean the system is unuseable now, need to fix it

Comment: I see.  Thank you for explaining all that.  I think you will need to reinstall, and this time, please have the internet connected so that Ubuntu can install any drivers it needs to make your computer run properly.  I would also advice ALWAYS testing the computer by booting to the install disk first.  It beats unpleasant surprises.

Comment: by "booting to the install disk" do you mean the demo?

Comment: When you say "demo" I think you mean like a video.  The "try ubuntu without making changes to your computer" is way more than a demo.  Those are incredibly powerful superuser mode disks.  They can actually DO MORE (good or bad) than an installation on the hard drive.  If you read many of the posts in this forum you'll find that we periodically refer to using a live CD to perform tasks which are difficult to impossible from within an installation.  They have still other uses, but I'd run out of characters before I listed them all.

Comment: Sorry just one more thing, if ubuntu isnt my main OS, is it actually better to put ubuntu for example in flash drive(usb3 for max speed) and run the "try ubuntu" whenever I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking this discussion out of commentary and into answer mode as we are getting to a point which regards some of my expertise. When you ask if it is better to put Ubuntu "in flash drive(usb3 for max speed) and run the "try ubuntu" whenever I want?", you are discussing doing something very similar to what I do every day, except that my flash drives actually contain complete installations that you can write to, which an image of a live cd on flash would not do.

I can answer that two different ways, both "yes".  yes it is better, which is why I do it.  My portable complete installation is better because I can boot my personal OS anywhere there is a pc, whether it belongs to me or someone else who trusts me.  It is versatile.  Even an image of a CD-rom is versatile, though annoying that you can't write to it or install new software.

If you intend to make an installation to a flash drive as I have done, you must do so on a computer in which you have temporarily disabled the hard drive.  If you do not, the internal windows hard drive will be essentially corrupted by the installation of the grubloader and suddenly that computer will become unable to even boot to windows unless the flash drive is inserted.

So, to recap my original solution revealed through comment discussion.  My advice was to reinstall Ubuntu but this time connected to the internet so that Ubuntu is better able to install properly.  I also suggested using the live-cd to check the hard drive for errors before even proceeding to install to it again.

(comments are automatically deleted after a time.  These "answers", which may benefit others, are retained indefinitely.)

PS:  about running from flash drives.  Most so-called usb3 flash drives are just as slow as usb2 because the chips are slow.  Patriot makes fast and slow units and the more expensive ones have little raids inside and go very fast.  That's what I use for units I make for my friends.  For myself I use something still faster and more expensive, combining an mSATA card case to usb3 adapter and then whatever size of mSATA solid state drive I choose to use.  I have two currently one is 64g and the other is 128g.

The [case](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I4701O6).  The [drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B3X72OU).

One more thing.  This is going to sound crackers, but after investing in these supposed usb3 drives I found that computers with usb3 ports don't play well with them so now I use them only with usb2 ports.  They aren't remotely slow though, and faster than the patriots I mentioned.